# ffmpeg - Have troubling syncing up audio and video together

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a webcam and a separate mic. I want to record what is happening.

It almost works, however the audio seems to play quickly and parts missing while playing over the video.

This is the command I am currently using to get it partially working

`ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f alsa -ac 1 -i plughw:1,0 -f video4linux2 -thread_queue_size 1024 -re -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -r 25 -f avi -q:a 2 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 96k out.mp4`

I have tried other arguments, but unsure if it has to do with the formats I am using or incorrect parameter settings.

Also, the next part would be how to stream it. Everytime I try going through rtp it complains about multiple streams. I tried doing html as well, but didn't like the format. `html html://localhost:50000/live_feed` or `rts rts://localhost:5000`

edit:

I am running this on a rpi 3.

Comment: Skip the `-re` and `-f avi`.

Comment: @Mulvya I did as you recommended. It came out worse and now frames are dropping. I am currently playing with ffserver to see if it can do it better for me.

Comment: You should still not use those options. The `-f avi` is plain wrong if you want a MP4, and `-re` is to simulate a live stream for a non-live source, Use `-vf realtime` to limit processing speed for a live video input.

Comment: @Mulvya still resulting in the same thing even with the arguments still removed. I just left as mp4 just to get an output to view it. What I hope to do is be able to view the stream using rtsp and view in html, which currently doesn't support rtsp. So, perhaps something like mpeg4. I was just finding what info I can to get anything really working for `ffmpeg`